# Google Drive integration - edit, delete, download and update with my Android app

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have implemented Google Drive with my Android application. I am able to view all my files in the app. Now I want to implement delete and update of google drive files.

This is my current code:

```
public void OpenFileFromGoogleDrive() {

        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[]{"text/plain", "text/html"})
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } 
        catch (SendIntentException e) {    
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }    
    }

final ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {    
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {                 
                            OpenFileFromGoogleDrive();                           
                    }       
                }
            };

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                    final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {    
            case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:    
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        mFileId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

                    Log.e("file id", mFileId.getResourceId() + ""); //                    0B-KGM98PVf2SdkdYTFRXZlNjSjg
                    /*String url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id="+ mFileId.getResourceId();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);*/
                    options();
                }    
                break;

            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }
```

How to delete and update files using `DriveId`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this doing:

```
driveFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient,
        DriveId.decodeFromString(driveIdStr));
// Call to delete file.
driveFile.delete(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(deleteCallback);
```

Check google drive documentation for more info https://developers.google.com/drive/android/trash?hl=es-419

Comment: how can i make deleteCallback to delete    

 DriveFile driveFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient,
                    DriveId.decodeFromString(fileId));
// Call to delete file.
            driveFile.delete(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(deleteCallback);


deletecallback handler?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @AndroidRuntimeException's answer, you may want to check this [Working with File Contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files) documentation and this [Google Drive Android API Demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/).

To [edit](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/EditContentsActivity.java) a file:

```
/**
 * An activity to illustrate how to edit contents of a Drive file.
*/

public class EditContentsActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

private static final String TAG = "EditContentsActivity";

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);

    final ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
                return;
            }
            DriveId driveId = result.getDriveId();
            DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();
            new EditContentsAsyncTask(EditContentsActivity.this).execute(file);
        }
    };
    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FILE_ID)
          .setResultCallback(idCallback);
}
```

To [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/trash) a file:

```
/**
 * An activity to illustrate how to delete contents of a Drive file.
*/
driveFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient,
        DriveId.decodeFromString(driveIdStr));
// Call to delete file.
driveFile.delete(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(deleteCallback);
```

Hope this helps!